# In what order are creatures affected by the Sleep spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, sleep

I thought I understood the *sleep* spell, but now I'm confused about the order of creatures affected. I always thought it was from lowest current HP to highest.

However, near the end of the spell description, it says (emphasis mine):

> Subtract each creature’s hit points from the total before moving on to the creature with the next **lowest** hit points.

Which to me would indicate that we are going from highest to lowest.

Is this a typo? In which order are creatures suppose to be affected by the *sleep* spell?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no typo in the order of affected creatures. The order is from the creature with lowest current HP to the highest. You start by subtracting the lowest current HP creature then move to the ***next*** lowest (i.e., lowest to second lowest to third lowest, etc.) until the spell does not have enough HP to affect an entire creature.

Comment: It might have been more clear to say: "...before moving on to the **next** creature with the **lowest** hit points."

Comment: @JasonSmith I disagree: your wording would seem sensible in the case when multiple creatures have the same, lowest (current) HP, but doesn't then indicate that one should "continue up the chain" of HP values.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is in the text for *Sleep*:

> Creatures within 20 feet of a point you choose within range are
>   *affected in ascending order of their current hit points* (ignoring
>   unconscious creatures).

Ascending order means lowest to highest.